# Capitalizing the letter after a semicolon

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I've looked around the site and haven't been able to find anything that will convert the letter after a semicolon to a capital letter. I'm using sublime text 3, so basically I'm trying to find every letter after a semicolon and check if its a lower case and if it is i want it to be a capital letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Find What: ;([a-z])
Replace With: ;\u\1
```

**Explanation**:

```
;          # match ';'
(          # group and capture to \1:
  [a-z]    #   any character of: 'a' to 'z'
)          # end of \1
```

`\u` will change the case of the first character of the backreference to upper case.